# Angular directive controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to develop a directive that has it's own controller so it can collect the data it need's from the API and be injected anywhere.

Here's what I got so far:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.hostelsmg.bookings')
    .directive('bookingsChart', bookingsChart);

function bookingsChart() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: [function(){
            $scope.test = 'Hi there!';
        }],
        compile: function(tElem, attrs){
            tElem.html('{{test}}');
            return function(scope, elems, attrs){

            }
        }
     }
 }
})();
```

So what I'd like, is the directive to get data from it's own controller. So far I couldn't get it to work that way.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Just inject `$scope` in your controller, and then use the variables assigned to `$scope` in your template directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
function bookingsChart() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        controller: ['$scope', 'yourservice', function ($scope, yourservice) {
            $scope.data = [];   //bind this data to your view

            $scope.getServiceData = function (count) {
                //your service call
                yourservice.getServiceData(count).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.data = data;  //sets data in $scope.data variable
                });
            }
        }],
        link: function (scope, elements, attributes) {
            //if you want to pass any parameters from your UI to your service method
            scope.getServiceData(attributes.count);    //calls the getServiceData in controller defined above 
        }
     }
 }
```